# Multiple analogRead() calls at timed intervals

Tags: arduino, atmega

I'm looking to add the ability to capture wave forms to an ATmega 328 based product and I've been unable to find details on how responsive the ATmega 328 is when doing A/D conversions.  The code is being prototyped on an Arduino, but will be migrated to custom board when done.

My plan is to have a total period (typically 16 to 20 milliseconds, based on local AC line frequency) and sample a single pin on the order of 50 to 100 times during that interval.  Can the ATmega 328 reliably perform that many conversions successively?  The minimum interval per conversion is 16ms / 100 = 160us.

I can add a code example if anyone has to see code, but right now I'm more concerned about the minimum period between multiple successive A/D conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a Arduino script and do some timing benchmarks for yourself.

The other way - doing this by spec - requires some more input for each involved level.

On the lowest level is the ATmega328 chip. The docs on the ADC part says:

> By default, the successive approximation circuitry requires an input clock frequency between 50 kHz and 200 kHz to get maximum resolution. If a lower resolution than 10 bits is needed, the input clock frequency to the ADC can be higher than 200 kHz to get a higher sample rate.

Assuming a 16 MHz clock for the ATMega the only available prescaler value for the ADC clock is 128 which is 125kHz for 10 bit resolution.  You could use the prescaler value 64 (250kHz) if you can get away with 8 bit resolution.

Next: The doc says:

> A normal conversion takes 13 ADC clock cycles. The first conversion after the ADC is switched on (ADEN in ADCSRA is set) takes 25 ADC clock cycles in order to initialize the analog circuitry.

So taking the 125kHz ADC clock this would mean ~9600Hz sample rate in "single conversion" mode. This is 104µs per sample. These are the Arduino defaults.

Compared to your requirement of 160µs this seems good.

**BUT**: So far only the conversion alone have been considered. You have to transfer the data somewhere. **ALSO** the Arduino `analogRead()` function has some overhead as you can see in the file `wiring_analog.c` in the Arduino dist.

This overhead might be to much - you have to test it for yourself.

On the other hand: Nobody forces you to use the Arduino `analogRead` function. Some available choices:

- you can ditch the overhead of `analogRead` and/or
- you can reconfigure the ADC to your needs (8 bit only, higher ADC clock) and/or
- you can use "advanced" modes like continuous sampling ("freerunning mode"9 of the ADC or
- you can use even interrupts to trigger the conversions.

Of course all of these choices heavily depend on your knowledge and time budget. :-)

Comment: Thanks!  That's the answer I was looking for.

The data is going to be copied off the chip after all the samples have been collected.

I can answer your "This overhead might be too much", I'm able to get 30kS/s with the rest of the overhead I have already.  This is far less (<= 6kS/s), but has to be more precisely timed and is a single pin.